# Chrome text is very bad

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, fonts, google-webfonts

When I visit jsfiddle using Chrome the text is unreadable.  Firefox and IE do not have this problem.

Here is a screen shot of the image in chrome, I do not even know what to call this font:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7ZRX.jpg

When I copy and paste the text into notepad the text displays just fine.

I have also found that if I disable the css property, text-rendering:optimizeLegibility; with the web-dev tool the text will display fine until I refresh the page.

Here is a screen shot in Chrome when I disable text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xn2e.jpg

I even uninstalled then re-installed chrome and it did not help.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does it happen on any other pages?  When did this start happening?  Are your language settings in Chrome correct?

Comment: It has been happening on jsFiddle for at least a month.  I noticed it on one other site but so far I have only found it on 2 sites.  I checked the language settings and I have it set for English (United States).

Comment: Did you try to update or re-install chrome?

Comment: Just reset your settings preferences. This may solve your problem although I think that you have a "Helvetica" font installed in your machine that's not working properly with your browser. You may try removing any "Helvetica" fonts from your OS just to check. It happened to me once and I was having similar problems to FF.

Comment: Also check if you have any custom user stylesheets set in Chrome. They're usually here in Win 7 and up: C:\Users\[your user name]\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\User StyleSheets

Comment: @otinanai I removed the Helvetica fonts but unfortunately that did not help

Comment: @jameh I see that there is one stylesheet there named Custom.css.  Should I remove that?

Comment: @Mdd, if it's empty, it's probably not doing anything. Worth poking inside the file to check it out though. Can always remove it temporarily or rename it to .old or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this problem I editted the file that jameh pointed to above.

The file is called Custom.css and I found it at this location:

C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets

In that file I added the following:

@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }

The issue seems to be with helvetica fonts and the text-rendering:optimizeLegibility CSS property.  I am not sure why this is an issue but this was how I resolved it.